# Head first servlet example not working

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am using tomcat 7 jdk 6 and trying to implement the example on page 81 edition 2008 of headfirst and the example is not working. I am getting an error: "HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class com.example.web.BeerSelect".

What to do?
my servlet code

```
     package com.exmaple.web;
     import javax.servlet.*;
     import javax.servlet.http.*;
     import java.io.*;
     public class BeerSelect extends Httpservlet{
     public class dopost(HttpServletRequest request,
         HttpServletResponse response)
         throws IOException,ServletException{
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            out.println("Beer Selection Advice<br>");

    String c=request.getParameter("color");
    out.println("<br>Got beer color"+c);
     }
       }
```

**my servlet path** C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\Beer-V1\WEB-INF\classes\com\example\web

**My xml code**

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
          <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
       version="3.0"
      metadata-complete="true">
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.example.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
        </web-app>
```

**also my jdk and tomacat are in diffrent folder**

Comment: Plz Put the code Which u have tried till now...:)so that we can get a Hint..

Comment: Hmmm....it seems that there is a problem while instantiating servlet class and thats not the end of the story, that class name is `com.example.web.BeerSelect`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Either you forgot to compile the servlet, or you don't have it in the right folder.

Comment: sorry guys i just wasn't expecting this kind of response

Comment: It looks like you are new to Java so maybe instead of learning Enterprise Edition (JEE) start with basic Standard Edition (Java SE). I have a feeling that this book mentions somewhere that you will need to know Java SE first so consider reading "Head first - Java" before "Head first - Servlets and JSP".

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Now that you included your code and configuration we can finally spot errors and propose some solutions</sub>

You made few mistakes. You need to know that Java is case-sensitive so there will be no

```
public class BeerSelect extends Httpservlet{
```

but

```
public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet {
//                                  ^ capital S.
```

---

Next thing is

```
public class dopost(HttpServletRequest request,
```

Here `dopost` should be `doPost`. Also this is not `class` but `method` which handles data send to servlet from some form. To make this code method you need to replace `class` with this method expected return type. Since this method will not actually return anything (it will just print something) you need to set its return type to `void`. So change this code to

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
//     ^^^^   ^ changes
```

---

Last thing is that you need to pay attention to what you are writing. In your

```
<servlet-class>com.example.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class>
```

you used

```
com.example.web.BeerSelect
```

but your class is in package `com.exmaple.web` ("ex **ma** ple" you have `ma` instead of `am`) so correct your package name to be `com.example.web`.